# IIS and Tomcat: mixed content

Tags: iis, tomcat, ajp

I'm trying to setup a site in IIS that is serving a webapp running in Tomcat, as well as content in HTML, PHP and JS. I'd like to have all content available under one domain. I was following [this guide](http://www.splinter.com.au/getting-iis-and-tomcat-to-play-nicely-with-is/) (using isapi_redirect.dll) to connect IIS and Tomcat. Unfortunately, ISAPI filters in IIS cannot be applied to only one folder (my plan was to attach the filter to a virtual folder, which handles the connection IIS -> Tomcat).

Since the filter is affecting my whole site, I'm only able to access the app running on Tomcat (e.g. *mydomain/app*, residing in c:\tomcat\webapps\app), but not the other content (e.g. *mydomain/phpmyadmin*, reisiding in c:\inetpub\mysite\phpmyadmin).

Is there any way around this?